# Trie data structure in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, trie

I have implemented a trie data structure in my way, though it is very similar to what major implementations I found but would like to get it reviewed by experts.

I don't see the need to store character in `TrieContainer` class as position within the series reflects the character stored. Maybe I am missing something and am wrong in my understanding.

Trie container

```
package trie;

public class TrieContainer{
    public boolean isEnd;
    public TrieContainer[] series = new TrieContainer[26];
}
```

Operations class

```
package trie;

public class Trie {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TrieContainer start = new TrieContainer();

        storeWords(start, "abc");
        storeWords(start, "abcd");
        storeWords(start, "abcde");
        storeWords(start, "india");
        storeWords(start, "hello");
        storeWords(start, "hell");

        printWordStrings(start,"");

        System.out.println("\n"+isWordPresent(start, "abcd"));
    }

    private static void storeWords(TrieContainer start, String word){
        for (int j = 0; j < word.length(); j++) {
            char character = word.charAt(j);

            //In series, check the position of character, 
            //if it is already filled then check the series of filled Trie object.
            //if it is not filled then create new TrieContainer object and place it at correct position, and check 
            //if it is end of the word, then mark isEnd = true or else false;  
            if(start.series[character-97]!=null){
                if(word.length()-1 == j){ //if word is found till last character, then mark the end as true.
                    start.series[character-97].isEnd = true;
                }
                start = start.series[character-97];
            }else{
                TrieContainer trie = new TrieContainer();
                trie.isEnd = (word.length()-1 == j ? true:false);
                start.series[character-97] = trie;
                start = start.series[character-97];
            }
        }       
    }

    private static boolean isWordPresent(TrieContainer start, String word){
        boolean isFound = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            char character = word.charAt(i);

            //if at character position TrieContainer object is present then character is found and 
            //start looking for next character is word. 
            if(start.series[character-97]!=null){
                if(word.length()-1 != i){
                    start = start.series[character-97];
                }else{
                    if(!start.series[character-97].isEnd){
                        isFound = false;
                    }
                }
            }else{
                isFound = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return isFound;
    }

    private static void printWordStrings(TrieContainer start, String toPrint) {
        if(start==null){
            return;
        }
        if(start.isEnd){
            System.out.println(toPrint);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < start.series.length; i++) {
            TrieContainer t = start.series[i];
            if(t!=null){
                printWordStrings(t, toPrint + (char)(97+i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`TrieContainer[26]` contains a magic number. Since we can calculate with `char` I'd write `TrieContainer['Z' - 'A' + 1]` to make it clear.

I'd use `System.out.printf("\n%b", isWordPresent(start, "abcd"))` rather than string concatenation `System.out.println("\n"+isWordPresent(start, "abcd")).`

I'd let `if` follow by a space to distinguish it from method invocations (as you do it with `for`). I'd also surround `else` with spaces.

You're inconsistent in surrounding operators with spaces or not. Do the former.

I'd rename `isFound` to `isWordFound`.

Since the variables `character` are just local to `for` I'd call them just `ch.`

`character-97` can be replaced with `ch - 'a'` then.

Array indices can be `char,` too. So:

```
for (int i = 0; i < start.series.length; i++) {
    ...
    ... (char)(97+i));
```

... can be changed to:

```
for (char ch = 0; ch < start.series.length; ch++) {
    ...
    ... (ch + 'a'));
```

I think `start` isn't an ideal name. With this `if(start.isEnd)` looks somehow irritating.

Having just `static` methods in `Trie` and `public` variables in `TrieContainer` doesn't look well-designed.